# deploy to repository prebuild artifacts Maven

Tags: maven

I have run `mvn install` on my project then at the end I wanted to run `mvn deploy -P profile1` to deploy selective modules from the project.

The issue is that mvn deploy performs build all over again when **I just want to deploy the artifacts that were already compiled.**

How do I do that?

Comment: Can't you simply run `mvn deploy -P profile1`, since it includes the install step? Why do you need to run `mvn install` before that?

Comment: Because in order to compile the project I need to compile few other modules. At end I only want to upload the final product, which is only 1 of the modules in the project.

Comment: You can try using "mvn deploy:deploy -P profile1" as command. That build process looks rather strange, as not deploying dependencies of modules you deploy is unusual.